# Why I am getting this error - Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Aniket' command not found: create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install

I have installing react app using this command

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app
```

Then I got Error like this:

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Aniket'
command not found: create-react-app
```

I have seen some online resources they are saying I have to remove space from my Windows Username, isn't there any other way of make this work?

Comment: The surest fix would be to just make sure your terminal is running as administrator. You can set it as default for your terminal in advanced shortcut properties.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Make sure you've **node>=8.10 and npm>=5.6** already installed

Try installing it globally first, using the command

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

And then, you can create your app using the command,

```
npx create-react-app <Name of your app>
```

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**: Above solution might work but it's not recommended way of solving this issue. Please refer https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

I referred the solution given at bottom and some other posts to use below command:
npm config set cache "C:\Users\mycomputer~1name\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way for me is:

```
mkdir C:\cache
npm config set cache "C:\\cache"
```

And then run the command again.

Comment: what does this do? and why it worked? 

Answer (score 16):

Go to **c:/users** open command prompt and run `dir /x` check shorter name you found with dir/x as shown in image and run `npm config set cache "C:/Users/<shortname-you-found-with-dir/x>/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache" --global`

In my case it's CYBERC~1.

[image: Configuration]

this works fine in my case.