# I'm trying to install react but I keep getting an 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npx

I've been trying to install react using `npx create-react-app ./`
That didn''t work so I tried `npm init react-app my-app` and it still didn't work.
The error im getting says

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Yanki' command not found: create-react-app
PS C: \Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\E-commerce-practice>

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to have  version of Node>=10.16 and  version of NPM >=5.6
If this is still not resolved then try this:

1. Clean cache with

- npm cache clean --force

2. Install the latest version of NPM globally as admin:

- npm install -g npm@latest --force

3.clean cache with

- npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen the ./ inclusion when creating a react app, but that's not to say it's wrong... maybe just follow the [docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) and use:
`npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: thanks but I think I figured it out, I just had to update the lastest version of node using npm install -g npm@latest and npm install -g yarn

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer it helped me so I hope this helps. Below is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65516052/8195649

Go to c:/users open command prompt and run dir /x check shorter name you found with dir/x as shown in image and run npm config set cache "C:/Users/<shortname-you-found-with-dir/x>/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache" --global

Comment: please flag to close a question as dupe

Comment: Sure I will do so