# I'm having error while creating React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

EPERM operation not permitted,MkDir c:command not found create react app
Npx Create-react-app myap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why I am getting this error - Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\Aniket' command not found: create-react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62693482/why-i-am-getting-this-error-error-eperm-operation-not-permitted-mkdir-c-u)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Which OS do you use ?
If it's linux or mac try to use "sudo npx create-react-app myapp".
You could do this on windows too if you use bach.

Comment: Win 7 professional

Comment: You could use bash terminal. And use sudo command.